# React Select controlled props menuIsOpen no longer clickable menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native

I have been struggling with programatically opening/closing a React-Select component while still keeping the normal click functionality of the select element.

I needed to programatically open the select via JavaScript, which I have working using the menuIsOpen property.

I am not able to toggle the property isOpen on a click event of the closed select though.

First I tried adding a click event to the parent, but that overrides onChange event when the menu is open and an option is selected.

Here's an example of the problem I'm facing:

https://codesandbox.io/s/kmplx9yxl3?module=/example.js

I would like to still be able to click the select (name or arrow) to toggle open/close the dropdown, and keep the checkbox toggle functionality.

If anyone has any advice on what I can do to add the click event but still keep the functionality using menuIsOpen prop, that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<Select ...
       onChange={() => this.setState({ menuIsOpen: false })}
          onFocus={this.toggleMenuIsOpen}/>`
At the end of the twenty-first line you put a double semicolon.

Comment: I had to add onBlur={this.toggleMenuIsOpen}, but this was it!! Thanks so much!!